# Is a Riemannian metric a $2$-form?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

In Lee's Riemannian Manifolds; An introduction to Curvature, he defines a Riemannian metric as an element of $\Gamma(T^2_0M)$, a $(2,0)$-tensor. Is this the same thing as a $2$-form? Is there a difference between being a section of $T^\ast M\times T^\ast M$ and a section of $T^2_0M$? A difference between a $(2,0)$-tensor and $2$-form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a rather significant difference. I'm not sure how comfortable you are with various vector bundle constructions, but both 2-forms and metrics are special elements of $E = T^*M \otimes T^*M$ the second dual tensor power bundle, which is identified with the space of smooth varying bilinear maps (that is to say a section $q$ of the bundle $E$ is a bilinear map on each tangent space such that $q(X,Y)$ is smooth for every vector fields $X,Y$. 2-forms are the space of $q$ such that $q(X,Y) = -q(Y,X)$, while metrics are those which satisfy $q(X,Y) = q(Y,X)$ (symmetry vs antisymmetry) and also a condition that $q(X,X) \geq 0$ and is nonzero wherever $X$ is nonzero.

It might be helpful to think about this just as what these look like as bilinear maps on a tangent space. A metric looks like an inner product, whereas a form looks like $q(x,y) =  -q(y,x)$ which alternates, and has the (actually equivalent) property that $q(x,x) = 0$. This helps us capture the idea from our initial idea of Riemann integration that if we change the orientation of the integration we should change the sign of the integral.

Comment: Thank you very much. I get it now, so a $2$-form just has the properties that $\omega(X,Y)=-\omega(Y,X)$ (at every point $p\in M$). It doesn't have to be that $\omega(X,Y)$ is smooth. While a $(2,0)$-tensor has the only property of being a smooth function on $M$ for every 2 tangent vectors?

Comment: No, a (2,0) also has  a very special property. Letting $X$ be any non-zero tangent vector at $p$, we must have $q(X,X) > 0$, and $q(X,Y) = q(Y,X)$ (note here we have no sign change). The difference can also be seen like this: let $(x_1,x_2) =x, (y_1,y_2) = y$ be two vectors in the plane: a metric is a bilinear map that looks a lot like $(x,y) \mapsto x \cdot y$ the Euclidean inner product, whereas a 2-form looks a lot like $$\det\begin{pmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \\ y_1 & y_2 \end{pmatrix}$$
Also, it doesn't make sense to say $q(X,Y)$ is smooth for tangent vectors $X,Y$ at a point p...

Comment: I meant that if $X,Y$ are two smooth vector fields (so they give a tangent vector at each point, then $q(X,Y)$ gives a smooth function.

Comment: Ok thank you. I meant that $q(X,Y)$ is a smooth function of $M$ for any two vector fields, not tangent vectors. Ok so a $(2,0)$ tensor is symmetric and satisfies $q(X,X)>0$ and a $2$-form satisfies just antisymmetry.

Comment: @user162520: No, a *metric tensor* is a (2,0)-tensor which also has the properties of being symmetric and positive definite.